# Automatic (or a quick) way to add page numbers to a pdf document

Tags: macbook-pro, pdf

I have a macbook and am running Big Sur 11.2.2. I have some pdf documents with over a hundred pages that I need to put in page numbers. I'd rather not have to do this manually for every page, and was wondering if there's a quick way to do this?

Note that the pdf documents weren't originally word files, in which case I could just go into the word file and put in the page numbers and re-output it as a pdf.

Comment: You can use LaTeX for that quite easily. See for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18762/324

Answer (score 1):

I've written a python script that will add page numbers to a PDF (position of your choice, font, size, etc). It's designed to work as a Quick Action (aka Service) in an Automator workflow

The Quick Action can be downloaded from here:
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/tree/master/Quick_Actions

and then move it (after unzipping) to the Services folder of your user Library. *You may need to create the `~/Library/Services` folder, if it doesn't exist.*

The python script itself is here:

https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Automator_Scripts/pagenumber.py

It uses the macOS-bundled python2, so should run on any Mac from Leopard upward! The script options for size, font are on lines 88 and 89. It's configured to not put a number on page 1, which is usually a title page.

Comment: Since updating to MacOS 12.3 the python script by benwiggy stopped working. Apple removed python2 from the OS. Can someone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: @davidm You'll have to install python (ideally version 3) yourself. You'll also have to install pyobjc.  I've updated some of the scripts for python 3. They'll work in Automator workflows or Shortcuts.app shortcuts. https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Python3/pagenumber.py

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a current possibility for the matter.

There is a website for this

https://www.ilovepdf.com/de/pdf_seitenzahlen